# Windows Phone 8 Drag and Drop and LongListSelector

Tags: windows-phone-8, drag-and-drop, longlistselector

I want to reorder items in a LongListSelector using Drag and Drop, I have found a solution in CodePlex but it uses another control then please could someone help me on implementing a Drag and Drop Within a LongListSelector?

Comment: Drag and drop is not as simple or straightforward as you think. And there are multiple ways one can implement it using different gestures or UI controls.

Comment: this is why I am asking for help :)

Comment: you are asking for solution, not for help ;)

Comment: I want to say that I know it is not simple..., and yes am asking for solution and help

Comment: Let's start with basics, how do you want your drag and drop to work? From the user perspective, any idea?

Comment: I have a liste of items and with dragging one item to top for example this item will have order=1 and the others items must their orders+1, the user must see the animation of reordering